# Basic CSS for a text link question?

Tags: css

Below is the css for a text link in 4 different states - link,visited,hover, and active.

Do I need to do this css code for every type of link class I have, some of the classes do not even change the appearance. (link,visited,hover,active) If only the appearance of a text link changes for hover and link would I only need the classes below for those 2 or should I still use all 4?

```
<style>
a.comment_mod:link {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #003366;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.comment_mod:visited {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #003366;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.comment_mod:hover {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #000000;
}
a.comment_mod:active {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #003366;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no change between `:link` and `:visited`, you can omit the latter. Same if `:hover` and `:active` are the same. Then just define the commeon parts in `:link` and override what you want changed in `:hover`:

```
a.comment_mod:link {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #003366;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.comment_mod:hover {
    color: #000000;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #000000;
}
```

**Edit:** if you want `:active` (which is the style when the mouse button is down on the link) to look like `:link`, then specify both together. If you don't specify it, it will look like `:hover`. So to match your original styling:

```
a.comment_mod:link,
a.comment_mod:active
{
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #003366;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.comment_mod:hover {
    color: #000000;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, if all of your states share a common styling, you can just declare that style like so

```
a.comment_mod 
{
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

If a state changes the styling from the norm, then you declare it.

```
a.comment_mod:hover
{
 color: #000;
 border-bottom:1px dotted #000000;
}
```

You can declare the styling for multiple elements at the same time,if they share styles:

```
a.comment_mod:hover, a.other_mod:hover
{
 color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
a.comment_mod {
   ... defaults ...
}

a.comment_mod:active {
  ... only things that change ...
}
```